# How to print document in Black and white using Monochrome option Mac OS?

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox, java-print

- I am unable to print pdf with **MONOCHROME** option on *MAC*, even
  monochrome option is selected but still on **MAC** its printing in
  **COLOR** but on windows its working fine for both options **MONOCHROME** and **COLOR**.
- Plus, On *MAC* settings are disable even proper printer is connected.
  but the same code running on windows its working fine in every
  scenario.
- I am using **macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6**

  ```
  public boolean printFile(String fileUrl) {

  PrintService[] printServicesAll = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
  PrintService[] printServicesFiltered;
  PrintRequestAttributeSet attrib = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
  Rectangle screen = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
  String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
  attrib.add(new Copies(1));
  attrib.add(new sun.print.DialogOnTop());
  attrib.add(Chromaticity.MONOCHROME);
  attrib.add(DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);
  PrintService selectedPrintService = null;
  if (OS.contains("win")) {
      if (printServicesAll.length > 0) {
          printServicesFiltered = removeLogicalPrinters(printServicesAll);
          selectedPrintService = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, screen.width / 3, screen.height / 3, printServicesFiltered, printServicesFiltered[0], null, attrib);
      }
  } else if (OS.contains("mac")) {
      if (printServicesAll.length > 0) {
          selectedPrintService = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, screen.width / 3, screen.height / 3, printServicesAll, printServicesAll[0], null, attrib);
      }
  }

  if (attrib.get(Destination.class) != null) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Print to file option not allowed!");
      return false;
  } else {
      if (selectedPrintService != null)
          System.out.println("selected printer: " + selectedPrintService.getName());
      else
          return false;
      try {
          DocPrintJob job = selectedPrintService.createPrintJob();
          job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
              public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent event) {
                  System.out.println("data transfer complete");
              }

              public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent event) {
                  System.out.println("received no more events");
              }
          });

          print(selectedPrintService, fileUrl, attrib);

          /*File file = new File(filePath);
          Desktop.getDesktop().print(file);*/
          return true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return false;
      }
  }
  }
  ```

> Main Print File Method

```
private boolean print(PrintService printService, String fileUrl, PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes)
        throws PrintException {
    try {
        PDDocument pdf = null;
        String fileType = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("bmp") || fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("gif") || fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {
            try {
                InputStream in = new URL(fileUrl).openStream();

                PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
                BufferedImage bImg = ImageIO.read(in);
                float width = bImg.getWidth();
                float height = bImg.getHeight();
                PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
                document.addPage(page);

                PDImageXObject img = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bImg);
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
                contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                contentStream.close();
                in.close();
                pdf = document;
                PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                job.setPrintService(printService);
                job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pdf));
                job.print(attributes);
                pdf.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) {
            JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane(fileUrl);
            jEditorPane.print(null, null, false, printService, null, false);
        } else if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
            pdf = PDDocument.load(new URL(fileUrl).openStream());
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            job.setPrintService(printService);
            job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pdf));
            job.print(attributes);
            pdf.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new PrintException("Printer exception", e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

[image: Mac Print Dialog]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I tried grayscale with PDF box but that didnt help.